# VBA To Change BackColor Of Rectangle - Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, backcolor

So I'm trying to change the backcolor of a rectangle within Access. I know you can easily do this `Box1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)`, however I want to enter a value into a textbox and then display that color value as soon as you update the textbox.

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't.

Textbox1 = 0, 0, 0

```
Dim P1 as String
P1 = "RGB(" + Textbox1.text + ")"
Box1.Backcolor = P1
```

How can I go about changing the backcolor on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `split` the text, run the entries though `int` and feed it to `RGB`:

```
Dim A As Variant
A = Split(Textbox1.text,",")
Box1.BackColor = RGB(Int(A(0)),Int(A(1)), Int(A(2)))
```

Comment: Perhaps use val() rather than int to allow for any extra spaces and just get 0 on invalid values

Comment: @AlexK. Not a bad idea -- though I am pretty sure that `Int` tolerates spaces -- `Int("   1 ")` evaluates to 1.

Comment: I like the suggestion, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, Eval() should work for you. The function evaluates a string as if were code. Backcolor is a long, btw so I adjusted your code accordingly.

```
Dim P1 as Long
P1 = eval("RGB(" + Textbox1.text + ")")
Box1.Backcolor = P1
```

Or you can ditch P1 and do this:

```
Box1.Backcolor = eval("RGB(" + Textbox1.text + ")")
```

Depending on what you are doing, you might just want to use the built in color dialog instead of entering text in a textbox.

Here's the API declaration and re-usable function

```
Declare Sub wlib_AccColorDialog Lib "msaccess.exe" Alias "#53" (ByVal Hwnd As Long, lngRGB As Long)

Function ChooseColor(nDefColor As Variant) As Long
  Dim lngColor As Long
  wlib_AccColorDialog Screen.ActiveForm.Hwnd, nDefColor
  ChooseColor = nDefColor
End Function
```

And here would be your box call to these functions; it's passing the default color of the box so that will be chosen when the dialog is open.

```
Box1.BackColor = ChooseColor(Me.Box1.BackColor)
```