# Access Report Showing Each Records Color Value

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I've asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651864/vba-to-change-backcolor-of-rectangle-access), however now I want to create a report showing the color values entered for each record. I've been able to use a portion of the code used to enter the values, however when the report is loaded, all rectangles in the report showed the color value from record 1, not per each.

This was used to enter the values, which works:

```
Dim A As Variant
A = Split(Textbox1.text,",")
Box1.BackColor = RGB(Int(A(0)),Int(A(1)), Int(A(2)))
```

I added this code to the report, on current, on load events and neither worked. Maybe the code needs to go to another event?

How can I get the report to show the color for each record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must go into the `On Format` event of the `Details` section.

Note that this event only fires when you open the report in Print or Print Preview view, not in Report View.

Comment: So there's no event in the Report View to show these color values? Only in Print/Print Preview?

Comment: @Muhnamana: exactly. In Report View you can only use Conditional Formatting to format each record separately, but that doesn't help with your task.